# Удалять комментарии из раздела комментарии

Tags: предложение, комментарии, удаление-комментариев

Коллеги, предложение такое.

Удалять комментарии прямо из раздела ***`Комментарии`***, пример в скрине ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К чему это я...

У многих немалое количество комментариев. Не знаю как кто, но я свои периодический подчищаю. Например ищу какой то определенный и вижу много лишних и не нужных комментариев. Но всякий раз переходить по ссылке к тому или иному вопросу нудно и уходит много времени. Предлагаю добавить кнопку ***`удалить`*** добавить и в раздел комментариев, чтобы сразу можно было бы **кликнуть** и **удалить**

Comment: Идея неплохая, но не актуальная для всех, и зная администрацию SE - 99% что она не будет реализована.

Comment: @AntonSorokin, придерживаюсь такого же мнения... Но все же ***попытка не пытка***

Comment: Я просто периодами прохожусь по постам и удаляю многие свои комментарии, оставляю только те, которые действительно принесли пользу для вопроса и были оценены учасниками сообщества. Да, способ не самый удобный, но не требующий добавления какого-либо нового функционала на сайт.

Comment: @Air, а каким образом у вас темный фон на этом сайте?

Comment: @NewView, Это расширение для браузера [userstyles.org](https://userstyles.org/), думаю далее сам разберешься, там есть стили не только для **SO**. Ну а если не разберешься спрашивай...

Comment: @Air, спасибо :) очень приятная находка

Comment: Мне кажется, удалять комментарии не видя контекста — не очень хорошая идея

Answer (score 7):

Удаление комментариев имеет смысл в том случае, если причина по которой он был оставлен устранена, а для этого надо открыть исходный вопрос и посмотреть, так что смысла в кнопке не вижу

Comment: Ну если не помнишь суть коммента, можешь пройти по ссылке и прочит комментарии... Какие проблемы? А вот кнопка удалить не помешает...

Comment: Я же не предлагаю удалять все комментарии...

Comment: Тем более, что для удаления каменты, нужно проверить - был ли он прочитан адресатом (т.е. последовала ли какая-то реакция в вопросе.ответе.новом комментарии)

Comment: @Air если появится кнопка удалить отдельный комментарий, люди захотят иметь кнопку "удалить все".

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну ***не все же коту масленится...***

Comment: @Air http://tsya.ru/ :-)